# R method for comparing NAs between two vectors

Tags: r, vector, logic, na, logical-operators

I am trying to compare two vectors for identical elements, say for vectors a and b below.

```
# vectors a and b
a <- c(1, 2, 3, NA)
b <- c(1, 3, NA, NA)

# compare for identity
a == b

## [1]  TRUE FALSE    NA    NA
```

However, I would like the comparison to include NA's, so that when both elements in a given position are NA then the result is TRUE, but if only one is NA then is is FALSE. For that I have written the function below.

```
# function to include NA's in the comparison
compare_incl_NA <- function(vec1, vec2){
  res = ifelse(is.na(vec1) | is.na(vec2), 
               is.na(vec1) & is.na(vec2), 
               vec1 == vec2)
  res
}

# run function
compare_incl_NA(a,b)

## [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

It produces the desired output and works fine for my purposes, but I am curious to know whether there is some inbuilt functionality for doing this or, if not, whether the function I have written is the most efficient way of producing this result.

Comment: It's important to point out that `NA` and `NULL` are different concepts in R. A numeric vector cannot contain a `NULL`, but can contain an `NA`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `identical` along with `mapply`. For example

```
mapply(identical, a, b)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: `identical` was certainly worth a read as I see I've largely been misusing `==` & etc.

Comment: This is perfect. I had been fiddling around with `identical` for a while and am realising I definitely need to get a bit more familiar with the apply verbs. They have solved a few problems recently.

Answer (score 0):

The base set function `setequal` can compare two vectors and will consider NA to be equivalent:

```
setequal(a,b)
```

Comment: `setequal` will only return one overall TRUE/FALSE value comparing the entire vector. It will not return a TRUE/FALSE value for each element being compared. That is, you cannot tell which positions are different using this function.

Comment: Although if applied with `mapply` as above `setequal` does produce the same result. i.e. `mapply(setequal, a, b)`. Any reason why one might choose `identical` over `setequal` in this context?

Comment: `identical` is quite strict and includes the class of the object.  Therefore `setequal(as.numeric(NA),as.character(NA))` will be `TRUE` whereas `identical(as.numeric(NA),as.character(NA))` will be `FALSE`